# Do alternatives to Google AdSense bring better revenues all other things being equal?

Tags: google-adsense, revenue, alternative

Assuming the same number of ads on a page and the same traffic, do alternatives to Google AdSense bring more (less) revenues? Does anyone have experience to share?

Comment: this question really isn't a good question for this site: it depends on a lot of different factors and this is mainly a matter of opinion/whatever works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience is Google Ad's perform better because of the better related advertisers in their network. That said you can't make any assumptions like this or take peoples opinions.

Because your visitors are not their visitors. The ad's showing up are likely not the same so the only way to know for sure is test this yourself. Put Google Ad's on a page with ads from another network and see which convert better. Now are you talking about text ad's or display ad's or affiliate ads?

Comment: I was taking about any kind of ads.